# what is the byte length for different character set in java?

Tags: java, byte, ascii, cjk

I want to know the different byte length of character set provided by JVM. For example, ASCII, non-acsii char set, chinese characters and so on.

Any idea thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Charset.availableCharsets().values();`, iterate over the list and print some predefined string into ByteArrayOutputStream. Then get bytes and see the array length.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII, CP*, and ISO 8859-* are 1 byte. UCS-2 is 2 bytes. UTF-16 is 2 or 4 bytes. UTF-32 and UCS-4 are 4 bytes. Most others (UTF-8, GB2312, EUC-JP, ShiftJIS, etc.) are variable.

Comment: "2 or 4 bytes" (for UTF-16) sounds variable as well! ;-)